# linear independence of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a $k\times k$ matrix 
and if $\{v_{1},v_{2},\cdots,v_{k}\}$ is a linearly independent set
of $k$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then the rows of the product
[
A\begin{bmatrix}v_{1}\\
v_{2}\\
\vdots\\
v_{k}
\end{bmatrix}
]
are linearly independent if and only if $A$ is invertible.

Is this true or false? Can someone help me out?

Comment: True, since $\det(A)\neq0$ in this case.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Can you explain how determinant is related to the linear independence here?

Comment: This is true, and the way to see this depends a lot on what you already know. So if you want an answer that's useful to you (other than "it's true"), you'll have to explain more about your own thoughts and about what you already know.

Comment: @Mark Of course, but it's too long to put it in a comment.

Comment: @Magdiragdag If $A$ is invertible, then the columns of $A$ are linearly independent. Product of two square matrices that are both linearly independent is also linearly independent. But I have a question, what if $A$ is singular? Is there any Singular matrix $A$ that may make the product of two matrices linearly independent?

Answer (score 0):

The statement is true. If $A$ is invertible, then the determinant of $A$ is not zero. A matrix is linearly dependent if and only if the determinant of the matrix formed by taking the vectors as its columns is zero. So, matrix formed by $k$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ has non zero determinant. From the determinant of matrix product, $det(A)det(B)=det(AB)$, we know that 
[
A\begin{bmatrix}v_{1}\\
v_{2}\\
\vdots\\
v_{k}
\end{bmatrix}
]
has non zero determinant, therefore it is linearly independent. If $A$ is not invertible, then $det(A)=0$ and $det(AB)=0$ which makes the matrix product linearly dependent. Therefore the statement is true.

Comment: @Magdiragdag Is the answer convincing enough?